# JSONP secure-connection workaround

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, jsonp

I usually make JSONP requests to another domain from the root of my website, https://example.com/ , but I can't do that anymore, since I now use a secure connection. How can I still make an asynchronous request to an external domain, without having access blocked by browsers? If necessary, I can restrict https only to the sign in/up page, but that isn't preferred.

Comment: I might be wrong here, since I never tried it. However, are you sure that JSONP isn't working over HTTPS? As far as I know it should. What is the issue that you encountered? What's the error? Is it a certificate issue with the specific domain? Also, do you have any control over that domain?

Comment: Yep, i'm sure. Browsers block the insecure content (at least IE and Chrome do), and prevent the request altogether. There is no error, just a browser warning. It is with the specific domain. I have total control over that domain as far as owning a Virtual Private Server goes. No configuration available, or any other system level settings beyond an apache .htaccess file or php config files. I like the idea of a proxy; this'll be my first time doing external requests from the server... everything is harder with PHP afterall.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'll have to check. There's probably a cleaner solution if you are the domain owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical solution is to proxy the calls through your own server. For example, send a request to `yourpage.(aspx|php|jsf)` and then have that make the remote call to the server.

Comment: I have never had to make a request from PHP before. I did some homework, but I could use some clarification. To send that call from the server, would I use file_get_contents("http://www.external.com/?param1=...etc.") to get "some_callback({})" in response? also, if I echoed that in double quotes, would it automatically call my javascript callback function when the request is finished, and I will be able to access the data from the call via textContent in the call to my server? Or, will I have to pull the data out manually?

Comment: Not overly familiar with PHP, so I don't really know about that side of it. Because you're making a call from the server side, you don't have the JSONP restrictions imposed by the browser, so if the API can return plain JSON, then you can just mirror that back to your from your PHP proxy and consume it using `response.responseText`, assuming you're doing it via Ajax.